# Does `kill -p` really work?

Tags: shell, kill, man, documentation

In the man page of `kill` it is written as following

> SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
>   kill [ -s signal | -p ] [ -a ] [ -- ] pid ...
>   kill -l [ signal ]
>
>   -p     Specify  that kill should only print the process id (pid) of the
>           named processes, and not send any signals.
> ```

But as I tried many times in both RH and RHEL, command like `kill -s SIGHUP |-p 123` never worked and an error is always reported

> bash: -p: command not found

Did I make any mistakes?

Comment: Note that when you typed in the command, you removed the `[` `]` brackets, and replaced `signal` with `SIGHUP` and `pid` with `123`? Why did you do that? Because you know that the symbols `[`, `signal` and `pid` are meta-syntactic, rather than literal. They indicate what the syntax is. Well, the `|` symbol is the same thing: another meta-syntactic indicator of syntax. `[a | b]` means: optional syntactic item, which can be either `a` or `b` (but not both since it must be one item).

Comment: Thanks for your instruction. By the way, how do you pronounce `[a | b]`?

Comment: Hmm. "Optional A or B".

Answer (score 51):

```
kill [ -s signal | -p ]
```

This syntax in a manual page means:

> You can use `kill -s signal` **or** you can use `kill -p`, but you can't use both `-s` and `-p` at the same time.

The pipe (`|`) stands for (exclusive) or in the documentation, it's not part of the command.

When you type

```
foo | bar
```

in your shell, it will attempt to start `foo` and `bar`, and pipe the output of `foo` to the `bar` program. (That's the shell doing that, not `foo` (or `bar`), the `|` is not passed to either process.) In your case, the second part is `-p 123`, so the shell tries to find an executable called `-p` and fails with that error message.

Comment: Thanks, @Mat. So I give a command like `kill -p 123`. It says `bash: kill: p: invalid signal specification`. And `kill -p SIGINT 123` says the same thing. I don't think there is place to put the signal according to the syntax. Do you mind if you just give a demonstration of the use of the `-p` option?

Comment: @user43312: see slm's answer for that

Answer (score 32):

I think you're getting tripped on the fact that there is a builtin command to Bash called `kill`, along with the command `kill`.

```
$ type -a kill
kill is a shell builtin
kill is /usr/bin/kill
kill is /bin/kill
```

The man page you're reading is referring to the `kill` command located under `/bin`. Use the full path to summon it:

```
$ /bin/kill -p sleep
16486
```

Incidentally the `/usr/bin/kill` is just a link to `/bin/kill`.

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/kill
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 14 Feb  9  2011 /usr/bin/kill -> ../../bin/kill

$ readlink -m /usr/bin/kill
/bin/kill
```

Comment: This really works. And I appreciate for all the demos.

Comment: @user43312 - NP. Examples are always easier to follow than man pages 8-).